# Ошибка парсинга ConfigParser

Tags: c++, conan

Есть проблема определения команд СonfigParser'ом. Выполнял следующую последовательность действий:

1. Установил conan с помощью conda.
2. Затем установил и собрал библиотеку boost из репозитория conan-community. Сборка осуществлялась с помощью Visual Studio 2019.
3. Далее делал всё по инструкции репозитория.

В результате получаю следующую ошибку при установке из conanfile.txt:

> ConfigParser: Unexpected line '[requires]'

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: покажите ваш conanfile.txt

Comment: `[requires]
boost/1.69.0@conan/stable

[generators]
txt`

Comment: можете загрузить сам файл целиком как вложение?

Comment: попробуйте сохранить файл в формате UTF-8 без BOM.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и написал `uilianries`, проблема была в кодировке. Парсер не может определить директивы при использовании кодировки `UTF-8 with BOM`.

Cохранил файл в формате UTF-8 без BOM - проблема исчезла.